# Build a select with optgroups/options based on a 3-way entities relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Well, the title isn't really explicit, but it's hard to explain my problem in only 1 sentence.

I'm using Symfony 2 with Doctrine.

What I want doesn't seem over complicated, yet I can't get it. (Though, I already solved problem which seemed much more complicated than this one...)

Here is my `Foo` entity. One `Foo` can have multiple `Bar`, but a `Bar` only have 1 `Foo`.

```
class Foo
{
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Bar", mappedBy="foo")
     */
    private $bars;
}
```

Here is my `Bar` entity. It has 1 `Foo`. It can have multiple `Baz`, and a `Baz` can belong to many `Bar` :

```
class Bar
{
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Foo", inversedBy="bars")
     */
    private $foo;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Baz")
     * @JoinTable(name="BarsBazs")
     */
    private $bazs;

}
```

Finally, here is the `Baz` entity. It belongs to one or more `Bar` :

```
class Baz
{

}
```

If I have a `Foo` entity instance, how can I get a `<select>` containing all the `Baz` of `Foo`, grouped by `Bar` (with `<optgroup>` ), with a minimum of db request?

**Edit:**

Ok, I went further.

My `Bar` entity is now:

```
class Bar
{
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Foo", inversedBy="bars")
     */
    private $foo;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Baz", inversedBy="bars")
     * @JoinTable(name="BarsBazs")
     */
    private $bazs;

}
```

And my `Baz` entity is now :

```
class Baz
{
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Bar", mappedBy="bazs")
     */
    private $bars;
}
```

In my form builder, when adding the field, I set it like that ($foo contains my `Foo` entity instance):

```
$builder->add('baz', 'entity', array(
    'property' => 'name',
    'query_builder' => function($repository) use ($foo) {
        return $repository->createQueryBuilder('z') // Baz
                    ->addSelect('r')                // Bar
                    ->join('z.bars', 'r')
                    ->where('r.foo = :fooId')
                    ->setParameter('fooId', $foo->getId())
                    ;
    }
));
```

It's almost OK. Now I have a select containing all the `baz` associated to the current `foo`. But I can't group them by `Bar`.

I tried the option `group_by` in many ways, but nothing works:

```
'group_by' => 'bars.name'
'group_by' => 'bar.name'
'group_by' => 'r.name'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally got it!

In my `Baz` entity, I added this method:

```
getFirstBar() {
    return $this->bars->first();
}
```

And in the options array of my field, I added this option:

```
$options['group_by'] = 'firstBar.name'
```

Now I have a `<select>` with all my `bazs` grouped by `bar` :)